# Selection Tool doesn't rotate in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, selections

Why my selection tool doesn't rotate object? I selected the object and it doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View > Show Bounding Box` will most likely "fix" your issue. You probably inadvertently turned off the bounding box.

Comment: Even with the bounding box on, in my case, I'm still not able to rotate:

https://imgur.com/a/VAwkyEj (unfortunately you can't see the mouse in this screenshot, but it's right next to the bottom right-hand corner).

Comment: Simply quitting Illustrator and restarting solved the problem : )